# QT Model/View Project doesnt show Strings from QList

Tags: qt, view, model, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel

My QTableView doesn't show strings from a QStringList.

In QTableWidget I have QTableWidgetItems. Must I set the strings manually or will the view show them automatically? In all the tutorials I don't see a "->setItem", they appear automatically.

I have 2 QLineEdits that give the QStrings to my Model :

```
void View::pushButtonClicked() {
  meinModel->setData(txtname->text(), txtvalue->text());
}
```

In setData I push the Strings in two QLists.

```
names.push_back(name);
values.push_back(value);
```

I emit a dataChanged signal with the index from topleft and bottomright.

```
QModelIndex topLeft = createIndex(names.size()+1,0);
QModelIndex bottomRights = createIndex(names.size()-1,1);
emit dataChanged(topLeft, bottomRights);
```

I have a QAbstractTableModel and so i override the columnCount, rowCount and data Method.
In my data() Method I return my value and name:

```
QString returnValue;
if(0 == index.column()) { returnValue = names.at(index.row()); }
```

All of this compiles without warnings, but doesn't work correctly :( Is there something I'm doing obviously wrong?

Comment: You don't show enough code to tell what's wrong. For example, the `setData` in your model doens't have the signature of `QAbstractItemModel::setData`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt 5.2 Model-View-Pattern: How to inform model object about changes in underlying data structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478746/qt-5-2-model-view-pattern-how-to-inform-model-object-about-changes-in-underlyin)

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem is that you didn't get the semantics of `dataChanged` correctly. `dataChanged` means that an *existing* item has changed its value. When you change the *structure* of the model by adding/removing rows or columns, you have to enclose the modification in `beginXxx` and `endXxx` calls - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21487724/1329652) for details.

For example:

```
void MyModel::setData(const QString & name, const QString & value) {
  beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), names.size(), names.size());
  names.push_back(name);
  values.push_back(value);
  endInsertRows();
}
```

Comment: Right ^^ 
i have forget to write that again in the setDat. 
I had it at some point deleted because the program with "begin.. and end.." crashes when you want to add something with the button :/

Comment: @thelittlePanda You absolutely must post a complete, self-contained example that reproduces the problem. Create a new project with just "main.cpp" in it, when you get the problem to reproduce, copy-paste it into your question. That way you won't forget any of such important details, and you won't waste everyone's time (*yours* included). We will be going in circles for the remainder of the year otherwise.

Comment: Sorry. I thought that here was a forum where you can ask when you have a Problem. With people who are eager to help( and Sacrifice your time)..
  Then the problem was just that I forgot something to write in again. I'm just a beginner :( I check my PRG again..

Comment: @thelittlePanda Sure you can ask, but for the question to be useful and **answerable**, it must not neglect the most basic information. If you fail to even correctly copy-paste the code, how can we answer anything? What I refer to by wasting time is pointing out mistakes that aren't really in the code that you're running, but in your sloppily written question. Quality questions lead to quality answers.