# Why TreeView Shows data not correctly?

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, treeview, qtquick2, qt-quick

TreeView Shows my data not correctly. What is wrong?

Here is the function of adding a child

```
bool TreeModel::addChild(const QVariant &data, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    Task *parentTask;
    if (!parent.isValid()){

        qDebug() << "addChild() - parent is not valid";
        parentTask = rootItem;
    }
    else
        parentTask = static_cast<Task*>(parent.internalPointer());

    Task *childTask = new Task(data, parentTask);
    qDebug() << QString::number((int)childTask);///

    int childCount = childTask->childCount();
    emit beginInsertRows(parent, childCount, childCount);
    parentTask->appendChild(childTask);

    emit endInsertRows();
    //emit dataChanged(parent, parent);

    return true;

}
```

In some situations calling this function from QML makes a mess with Indexes in QML. It start show wrong items or invalid items, especially when Parent has tasks with children (2 levels tree).
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're indicating the wrong number of children to the model's users.

Instead of `int childCount = childTask->childCount();`, you should have

```
int childCount = parentTask->childCount();
```

Since this is a structural change only, you should *never* emit the `dataChanged` signal. The parent's data has *not* changed. Its *structure* has. Qt's models discriminate between structural and data changes. The `begin...`/`end...` methods indicate structural changes. The only place you should be emitting `dataChanged` is from a location that has the effects of calling `Model::setData` on an *existing* item. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21487724/1329652), for example, for details.