# cpp Qt Model not updating QML view

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I am using a custom model for my **QML view** and I want to be able to move items thanks to a drag and drop.
I use a list in my cpp model to set Data and then I just bind my model to the `QML view`.

However, when I drop an item in a new position, **the view ask the model to move the item on is new position**.
In that purpose, I just **update my dataList** with the function `dataList.move(oldIndexPosition, newIndexPosition)`.
**My dataList is correctly updated but it doesn't refresh the QML view**.
I tried to use the signal `emit dataChanged()`but it is still **not refreshing the view**.

I don't understand what should I do, any suggestion ?

Here is a simple example of what I try to do. Notice that there is no drag and drop here, in order to make it easier to understand:

```
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void move(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
              dataList.move(oldIndex,newIndex);
              emit dataChanged(this->index(oldIndex),this->index(newIndex));
    }

signals:
    void dataChanged(const QModelIndex & topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight);
```

*model.h*

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Model model;
    model.addSomeData("data1");
    model.addSomeData("data2");
    model.addSomeData("data3");

    QQuickView view;
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    QQmlContext *ctxt = view.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", &model);

    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:view.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
ListView {
    width: 200; height: 250

    model: myModel
    delegate: Text { text: "data " + data  }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
        onClicked: {
            myModel.move(0,2) //Just a test
        }
    }
}
```

*myqml.qml*

If you have any idea of what I am doing wrong, that would be really kind of you to help me! Thank you very much.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21478746/1329652

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed this thread !

Answer (score 4):

I assume `Model` is an implementation of [`QAbstractItemModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html). In that case, you should call [`QAbstractItemModel::beginMoveRows`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginMoveRows) before you start moving your data and [`QAbstractItemModel::endMoveRows`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#endMoveRows) to finalise it.

```
Q_INVOKABLE void move(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    QModelIndex parent;
    beginMoveRows(parent, oldIndex, oldIndex, parent, newIndex);
    dataList.move(oldIndex,newIndex);
    endMoveRows();
}
```

Comment: I guess you meant to begin moving rows, not columns in your example.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am currently not at work but this is what I need and I will check it as soon as possible !